# I cannot use folder path in css in my react app

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, css-loader

I cannot set img background in css at all in my react app. but if I style and set img from react component then it works fine, can someone help me out

this will work

```
const style={
    width:'300px',
    height:'200px',
    backgroundImage: 'url(pictures/backgroundPics/1.jpg)'
}

const Test =()=>(  
    <div style={style}/>
)
```

but this won't

```
import './test.css'

const Test =()=>(  
    <div className='test'/>
)
```

css

```
.test{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(../../public/pictures/randomPics/1.jpg)
}
```

i have tried to set my css path to many ways I can think of including setting it relative to css file or html file but it either gives me module not found or parse error. my Test component path is src/test/test.js and my css file is in the same test folder. I am using css-loader v0.28.4

It will work if I set web address as the url

```
background-image: url(http://www.pvhc.net/img226/gzypyldoqaxjhvtyyhei.png)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to relativity reference the `public` directory in your CSS. Have you tried:

```
background-image: url(/pictures/randomPics/1.jpg)
```

Comment: it does not work for me, I tried that. I included my error in my question, please take a look, thanks

Comment: I meant to include `/pictures` not `pictures`. I updated the snippet above.